# Reactjs redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with redirecting from one page to another. I used Link from the react-router-dom. The problem is that whenever I click on the link, I can see that the url changes; however, the page still stays the same. I have to manually click on the url and click enter to redirect the page. I included the code as well as the picture of the browser.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import { login, logout, register } from '../actions/auth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      nestedModal: false,
      closeAll: false,
      email: '',
      password: '',

      confirmPassword:'',
      registerEmail: '',
      registerPassword: '',
      firstName:'',
      lastName:'',
      address:'',
      city:'',
      state:'',
      zipcode:'',
      phoneNumber:'',
      user: {},
      isLoggedIn: false
    };

  }
  
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.user !== state.user){
      return {
        ...state,
        user: props.user
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

  userLogin (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       this.props.login({
         email: this.state.email,
         password: this.state.password
       });
       this.setState({
         modal: !this.state.modal,
         isLoggedIn: true
       });
  }

  userRegister (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       this.props.register({
         email: this.state.registerEmail,
         password: this.state.registerPassword,
         name: this.state.firstName + ' ' + this.state.lastName,
         address:this.state.address + ' ' + this.state.city + ' ' + this.state.state + ' ' + this.state.zipcode,
         city:this.state.city,
         state:this.state.state,
         zipcode:this.state.zipcode,
         confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword,
         phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber
       });
       this.setState({
         modal: !this.state.modal
       });
  }

  userLogout(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout();
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn:false
    })
  }


  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });

  }

  toggleNested() {
    this.setState({
      nestedModal: !this.state.nestedModal,
      closeAll: false
    });
  }

  toggleAll() {
    this.setState({
      nestedModal: !this.state.nestedModal,
      closeAll: true
    });
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.user)
      return(
        <div>  <NavLink style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={this.userLogout.bind(this)}>Log Out</NavLink></div>
      );

    else
      return (
        <div >
          <NavLink style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Log In</NavLink>
          <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)} className={this.props.className}>

            <ModalHeader className="login-header" toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Welcome Back! </ModalHeader>

            <ModalBody>
              <Form className = "login-body"   >
                  <FormGroup>
                      <Label for="exampleEmail">Email:</Label>
                      <Input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} id='exampleEmail' placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                      <Label for="examplePassword">Password:</Label>
                      <Input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password}  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} id='examplePassword' placeholder="Enter Your Password" />
                  </FormGroup>
              </Form>

              <Link to='/register'>Not a member yet? Sign Up</Link>
            </ModalBody>

            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color="info" onClick={this.userLogin.bind(this)}>Log In</Button>{' '}
              <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    if(!!state.auth.user){
        return {
            isLoggedIn: !!state.auth.user,
            user: state.auth.user.data
        };
    }
}

export  default connect(mapStateToProps, { login, logout, register })(Login)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

[Here is the picture of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g2Ld.png)

Comment: `<a href="/to"/> click me </a>` ?

Comment: Thank you that helped. I dont know why <Link to ""> doesnt do anything except writing out the url without executing the url

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `<Navlink>` to redirect user under some condition

there is a `Redirect` component that comes from `react-router-dom` pkg

all you need to do is just change this

```
if (this.state.user)
  return(
    <div>  <NavLink style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={this.userLogout.bind(this)}>Log Out</NavLink></div>
  );
```

to something like this

```
if (this.state.user) {
  <Redirect to='/path/that/in/your/mind'>
}
```

first of , please import it from `react-router-dom` then use it.

basically you saying that if your user is logged in (`this.state.user`) , then redirect to `/path/that/in/your/mind` page.

Answer (score 1):

**I believe you have some issues on the router mapping, into the index.js**

If the url changes that mean react-router-dom and  work fine.

Maybe you have some trouble with mapping and component. Other pages have the same trouble? Can you share to us the index.js code?

Answer (score 1):

`<Link />` is a React-DOM component meant for React-Dom redirects, so clicking on it changes the url and remounts the `<Route/>`s accordingly. For a real http redirect you could use the good old `<a />`